# How can i access an property of an object within an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
var userdata = { 

     data:{ 
            "email": "sdafs@gmail.com",
            "phone":7894561230,
            "opcrmMobile": 57892445
           }
}
```

here i need to acess phone `opcrmMobile` and `email`.

I have

```
var store= userdata.data.opcrmMobile;
```

and

```
var mail=userdata.data.email;
```

but when i use `console.log(store);` and `console.log(mail);`

i get `userdata.data.opcrmMobile` like this.

but i need the number that is available in the code

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789141/access-object-properties-within-object) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659792/access-javascript-object-literal-value-in-same-object).

Comment: `i get userdata.data.opcrmMobile like this.` ?? like what ?

Comment: can you show us the code with console.log statements... ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you are accessing the object property should work fine.

```
var userdata = { 
  data:{ 
    "email": "sdafs@gmail.com",
    "phone": 7894561230,
    "opcrmMobile": 57892445
  }
};

var store= userdata.data.opcrmMobile;
// or
var store= userdata.data["opcrmMobile"];

console.log(store);  // should output "sdafs@gmail.com"
```

You can still access the properties even if their names are not written as a string literal i.e. `"email"` or `email`, `"phone"` or `phone`, nothing mysterious here.

```
var userdata = { 
  data:{ 
    email: "sdafs@gmail.com",
    phone: 7894561230,
    opcrmMobile: 57892445
  }
};

console.log(userdata.data.email);
console.log(userdata.data.phone);
console.log(userdata.data.opcrmMobile);

console.log(userdata.data["email"]);
console.log(userdata.data["phone"]);
console.log(userdata.data["opcrmMobile"]);

console.log("show my object properties: " + Object.keys(userdata.data));
```

**[Check Output here](http://jsbin.com/nevine/edit?js,console)**. There is no celebrity code, just emphasized what you were trying to do.

---

Besides, it depends upon the use case that whether you need to use the dot (.) or square bracket `[]` notation to access object properties.

This is a nice brief [**overview of accessing the object properties with dot `.` vs square bracket `[]` notation.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation#answer-17189764)

Comment: then what's the difference between `userdata.data.opcrmMobile` and `userdata.data["opcrmMobile"]` ..

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi not really a big difference, it's just, the one with brackets allows you to to access objects inside objects where keys are number just like if you have for example something like this `data={0: 'email', 1: 'phone'}` 
and in this case, you can't use `data.0` to get the data value of index 0, but you use `data[0]` instead

Comment: thanks for the info mate @david_smithe i just asked in respect of the op's problem ? like why converting from `userdata.data.opcrmMobile`  to `userdata.data["opcrmMobile"]` will solve op's problem

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, i hope i have done justice with my comment, please let me know if i messed up things? we all are here to help and learn....

Comment: i was wanted to bring the point that converting from `userdata.data.opcrmMobile` to `userdata.data["opcrmMobile"]` won't anything here in term of op's problem . nothing else mate @Rohit416 :)

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi ohh, alright, my bad mate, I didn't review the edit history. :D

Comment: Updated answer to something better than earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var userdata = { 
     data:{ 
            "email": "sdafs@gmail.com",
            "phone":7894561230,
            "opcrmMobile": 57892445
           }
}
console.log(userdata.data.email)
console.log(userdata.data.opcrmMobile)

store = userdata.data.opcrmMobile;
mail = userdata.data.email;

console.log('mail : ' + mail);
console.log('store : ' + store);
```