# Accessing properties in same object literal

Tags: javascript

I always thought we can't access JS Object Literal value in same object as stated here,

[Access JavaScript Object Literal value in same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659792/access-javascript-object-literal-value-in-same-object)

But I came across [this library](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) which is doing exactly opposite. It most likely be something I am missing but I can't figure it out.

Here is how library doing it,
http://image.prntscr.com/image/2cd771f00f604b51be4b7befca49709e.png

And it's not using "this" as well to access "defaults"

**Edit**

Seems like latest revision of library doesn't has the same code. But I am looking at exercise files of this course,

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/typescript/table-of-contents

Comment: HI, where do you find that code? I had taken latest and in that code, they are using functions to access the defaults ` function getOptions() {
                return $.extend({}, getDefaults(), toastr.options);
            }`

Comment: @VinodKumarKashyap I updated with link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're confused between object properties and variable.

`Default` is variable not object property.
[image]

For more detail, let's see  [lexical scoping example in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Lexical_scoping)

> The **getOptions** function has no local variables of its own. However,
>   because inner functions have access to the variables of outer
>   functions, **getOptions()** can access the variable **default** declared in the
>   parent function

```js
function init() {
  var name = 'Mozilla'; // name is a local variable created by init
  function displayName() { // displayName() is the inner function, a closure
    alert(name); // use variable declared in the parent function    
  }
  displayName();    
}
init();
```

Comment: Tai, in your example you are not self accessing variable or property like it's happening in the example, if I make sense ?

Comment: @mathematics did you see my attached pic. The var keyword before defaults is the point you should notice..