# How to inherit style within StyleSheet.create in React Native (using destructuring syntax maybe)

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-native-stylesheet

**I want to reuse styles within `StyleSheet.create`'s parameter object, how to do that?**

See the code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  style1: {
    color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  style2: {
    width: 100,
    ...style1
  }
})
```

Originally, I want `style2` to inherit all `color` and `backgroundColor` from `style1`, and expand 1 more property called `width`. So I did try the code above, but then it got an error "style1 is not declared".
I realized the problem, so I replaced `...style1` with `...this.style1`, the error went away, but it didn't work as I expected. I wondered why and tried running this snippet in javascript to test the behavior:

```js
styles = {
  style1: {
    color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  style2: {
    width: 100,
    inherit: this.style1
  }
}
console.log(styles.style2.inherit)
```

It pooped out the result `undefined`, which is not `styles.style1`. I realized the problem again and after replacing `inherit: this.style1` with `inherit: styles.style1`, the **javascript snippet** works, but **not** in the React Native code.

I think until now, you understand what I want, so my question is how could I achieve that (reuse style code in React Native)? I think there would be many workarounds, so please give me as many as you can. Thank you.

Here is the list of syntaxes I did try but not get the expected result (or as my brain is not working well, I was wrong):

```
...style1
...this.style1
...styles.style1
...StyleSheet.style1
...StyleSheet.flatten(styles.style1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to React Native so if there's something wrong with my question, pardon me.

Answer (score 8):

It's impossible to [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659792/access-javascript-object-literal-value-in-same-object)

Solution: 1

```
const baseStyle = {
  color: 'red',
  backgroundColor: 'white'
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  style1: baseStyle,
  style2: {
    width: 100,
    ...baseStyle
  }
})
```

Solution 2
Use [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/) to manage and reuse styles easily.

Comment: I'll take a look at `Styled Components` later. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I know 1 workaround is to put the "reuseable" `style1` object outside of `StyleSheet.create`:

```
const style1 = {
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "white"
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  style2: {
    width: 100,
    ...style1
  }
})
```

Is there a better way? Because `style1` can also be a style used by another element, I can't use `<Element style={styles.style1}/>` any more...

Answer (score 0):

a better way to reuse and compose stylesheet:

```
const baseStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: baseStyles.container,
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    ...baseStyles.container,
  },
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).